# Jquery fadeout slidedown not working

Tags: jquery, click

I am trying to use

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
        $( "#Bottom" ).delay(1000).slideDown( "slow" )});

        $( "#SuC" ).click(function() {
            $( "#Wrap" ).fadeOut( "slow" , function() {
                $( "#WrapSu" ).delay(2000).slideDown( "slow" )});
        });
```

but its not working, my button to click on is : `<a href="#" id="SuC">Sign up!</a>`

but it wont react, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: do you get any errors in console?

Comment: When this happens to me it is usually because I have a typo in the selector. What is the output of the following?
console.log('$( "#SuC" ).length: ' + $( "#SuC" ).length);
console.log('$( "#Wrap" ).length: ' + $( "#Wrap" ).length);
console.log('$( "#WrapSu" ).length: ' + $( "#WrapSu" ).length);
If the length value isn't 1, then you have a problem with the selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to wrap all code inside the ready function, here is a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/crCQ7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#Bottom" ).delay(1000).slideDown( "slow" );

    $( "#SuC" ).click(function() {
        $( "#Wrap" ).fadeOut( "slow" , function() {
            $( "#WrapSu" ).delay(2000).slideDown( "slow" )});
    });
});
```

Comment: Im now trying to change my border-radius:3px thats on the id, with jquery on click and have the following:

    $( "#SignUpb" ).click(function() {
     $( "$WrapSu" ).css({"border-radius":"0px 0px 3px 3px"});
    }); 

but doesnt work, would you know why?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close your functions with a semicolon , should be as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#Bottom").delay(1000).slideDown("slow");
 });

 $("#SuC").click(function () {
     $("#Wrap").fadeOut("slow", function () {
         $("#WrapSu").delay(2000).slideDown("slow");
     });
 });
```

EDIT:

also note that when you are attaching an event listener to a specific item, you have to make sure that this item has been rendered already therefore you should put your onclick into the:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
```

or instead of

```
$("#SuC").click(function () {
```

use

```
$(document).on("click","#SuC",function () {
```

Comment: still no reaction, i dont know why :o i got the first part about #bottom working, but the click doesnt go off

Comment: as far as I know, there is no `onclick` in jQuery, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Just FYI, `$("#SuC").click(function () {` is the same thing as `$("#SuC").on("click",function () {`. There is no jQuery method named onclick.